# how to set image to background n text color of action bar?

Tags: android

**I want so set backgroung image to actionbar of main activity and all activities too and also want to chnage text color of text of action bar 
i tried this code but it giving me error
plz help me**

style.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThe" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
</style>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style> 
</resources>`
```

manifest code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hp.navigationd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="OLXA"
        android:theme="@style/AppThe" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.MainActivity"
            android:label="OLXA" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.post_ad"
            android:label="@string/Ad_Details"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.hp.navigationd.MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.My_account" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.My_fav" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.My_ads" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.My_chats" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.Rules" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.Help" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.hp.navigationd.About_us" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what error? please share. Its better to edit your post with complete information.

Comment: What is the error? is it runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Insted of using,

`<style name="AppThe" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

use this,

`<style name="AppThe" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">`

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below style.

```
 <style name="AppThe" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
       <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
  </style>
  <style name="ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
       <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
  </style>
```

Here you need to use both you both `android:actionBarStyle and actionBarStyle`  as well as `android:background and background` items. The former is for newer versions of android that support ActionBar natively. The latter is for older android versions.

**About the error:** 
You can not use `"@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` with `AppCompatActivity`